# Why does each box in a UML state diagram have three sections?

Tags: uml, diagram

I noticed in this example that each box is divided into three sections, but only two sections are ever used.  Why not just divide it into two sections then?

[UML Tutorial - State Diagrams](http://web.archive.org/web/20060411060900/http://atlas.kennesaw.edu/~dbraun/csis4650/A%26D/UML_tutorial/state.htm)

Comment: What does your UML text book have to say on the topic?

Comment: The tutorial is eight years old, and is not consistent in its use of the three boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having checked my copy of UML Distilled by Fowler-Scott, I can only conclude that the use of different sections is not significant.  As you say, why not just use 2 sections, and I'd agree.

I would place more importance on what the diagram is trying to show and why that is important than on the actual representation used on the diagram itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there are only one or two sections. One for the name and a second one (often omited) for actions/activities.